# Windows Filtering Platform detecting & authorising outbound connections without first blocking?

Tags: connection, filtering, block, firewall, wfp

Before I even start researching WFP I need to know one thing:

Can I detect an outbound TCP connection attempt, pause it until the user clicks Allow/Block, and then accordingly allow it to succeed or block it?

Other WFP based software such as Windows 7 Firewall Control always blocks the first connection attempt. Clicking Allow only applies to subsequent connection attempts. The first attempt always fails and the blocked application assumes there is no internet and I have to restart the application.

Is it possible to pause until Allow/Block is clicked in WFP or is my only option to write a kernel-mode driver?